# Integral of a function with respect to a measure on a mixed space $[\![ N ]\!]\times \mathsf{X}$

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

## Task

$\newcommand{\intbrackets}[1]{[\![ #1 ]\!]}$
$\newcommand{\Pcal}{\mathcal{P}}$
I would like to better understand integration of a function $f$  with respect to a probability measure $\mu$  on a product measurable space
$$
(\mathsf{A}, \mathcal{A}) := (\intbrackets{N}\times \mathsf{X}, \,\,\Pcal(\intbrackets{N})\otimes \mathcal{X})
$$
where:

1. $N$ is a positive integer
2. $\intbrackets{N}= \{0, 1, 2, \ldots, N\}$
3. $\Pcal(\intbrackets{N})$ is the power set on $\intbrackets{N}$
4. $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ is another measurable space, typically $(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^d))$.

## Details

One typically writes
$$
\mu(f) = \int f \, d\mu
$$
In our case, however, we are working in $(\mathsf{A}, \mathcal{A})$ which is a mix of a discrete and continuous space. Therefore, I expect to write
$$
\mu(f) = \int_{\mathsf{A}} f(a) \mu(da) = \sum_{n=0}^N \int_\mathsf{X}f(n, x) \mu(n, dx)
$$
But it is unclear to me if one can **actually** write the integral in this sum-integral form or not. On one hand, one could technically resort to measurable rectangles or cylinder sets (which I have some intuition of). On the other hand, it is not necessarily clear to me that all integrations look like this. For instance, I can imagine a set $B\in\mathsf{A}$ which doesn't have the form $B = \{0, 1, \ldots, N\}\times dx$. Indeed, I could take any set $C\in\intbrackets{N}$ and any set $D\in\mathsf{X}$ and then their Cartesian product $C\times D$ would not necessarily have that form.

It seems to me then, that it might be worth defining this expectation on sets rather than the whole $\mathsf{A}$. Basically, I am very unsure how to perform the integration because I am unsure about how $\mu$ might be defined to act on these mixed sets.